# CSS style: Curvature of the table's edge (top only)

Tags: css

I am trying to make the top left and top right end of the table circular, but applying the following code will also make the bottom left and bottom right circular. Any idea how to fix it?

```
/* sets the curvature of the box */
border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-o-border-radius: 10px;
```

Answer (score 3):

Specify just top left and top right:

```
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
```

[border-radius.com](http://border-radius.com/) is a useful quick tool for creating border radius this way.

Comment: @TingPing No problem. I find it very useful. I haven't typed out border radius CSS since I found it!

Answer (score 2):

Used to this

```
border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
-moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
-o-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify each corner of the border with this property.  It goes as follows:

```
border-radius: [top-left] [top-right] [bottom-left] [bottom-right]

border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
-o-border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code and it will work

```
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
```